Permission for regular user to modify network settings?
I have a PC with a normal, unmodified, Ubuntu installation where I need to add a new normal user but I also need this new user to be able to modify network settings and am struggling a bit with how to allow that.
Network settings are mainly managed with Netplan and it's related yaml file but various "IP" commands like adding static routes are necessary as well for this new user.
I've figured out that I need to add this permission for the specific user to the sudoers configuration but am not sure exactly how to add an entry for Netplan, so any advice is strongly appreciated.
Also, is there an easy way to add a general permission for allowing network modification, e.g. adding the user to a group, or do I have to have an entry for each in sudoers, like IP route, etc?

Unfortunately I am restricted to using Netplan for modifying network settings on this specific machine so I think a permission-based solution is the only option, but will consider other options as well as long as they are based on Netplan

Apologies for not being totally clear.
This PC is in a corporate setting and the supplier of the PC would void guarantees (& support) if I change the networking to use NetworkManager.
Therefore I am restricted to using Netplan and finding a solution for this, and no, the supplier does not give the necessary support for helping me solve the intial question

Since the PC is "in a corporate setting", you must first become familiar with corporate policies that govern this situation. You're risking your job if you violate these policies

I am well aware of the policies that are relevant and what I am allowed and not allowed to do. What I want to do, as asked in the initial question, is permitted in the environment where I need to do this.
Could we please focus on the actual question?
Edit:
Seems user deleted their comments. My first two were answers to that user which sort of derailed my initial question.

I eventually figured it out and created a specific permissions file for the new user under /etc/sudoers.d
To give permission for netplan I needed to add /usr/sbin/netplan to that specific sudoers file.
It might not be the best solution but I also added sudo permission for that user to edit the specific configuration file for netplan, e.g. /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml, and restricting that editing to the vim editor
